# Regex searching for object instantiations not working

Tags: java, regex

I'm searching each line of files looking for object instantiation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String t = " foo = new Mango(kil(tile,go),y,x); //yank before comment

    String p ="//s+new//s+[a-zA-Z]+/(.*/);";

    Pattern pt = Pattern.compile(p);
    Matcher m = pt.matcher(t);

    if(m.find()){
        m.group(0);
        System.out.print("start at " + m.start());
        System.out.print("end at " + m.end());

    }
}
```

The regex is not matching the input. Nothing gets printed. I also tried using parentheses around it but still didn't work. I have stripped the regex of all parentheses.

Comment: Note that class names can contain characters other than `[a-zA-Z]` so this won't be quite right even if you change the `/` characters to \.

Answer (score 2):

Those slashes `/` should be backslashes `\`, and the last two should be doubled just like the first two.

```
String p = "\\s+new\\s+[a-zA-Z]+\\(.*\\);";
```